# Show values on Y Axis as it is with Higher and lower limits NVD3 Line Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a line chart with dummy data say

My graph is plotted perfectly but the values on Y axis are not showing in thousands.
The values in the below data will be from backend and in thousands only so need a solution to print the y axis as it is.

```
[{"key":"City31","values":[["1990",6428.59],["1991",7079.34],["1992",4014.61],["1993",4000.77],["1994",4005.34],["1995",4182.21],["1996",4034.73],["1997",5891.87],["1998",4735.89],["1999",4039.58],["2000",4000],["2001",5030.29],["2002",4000.03],["2003",4000.43],["2004",4321.92],["2005",12575.87],["2006",4000],["2007",4027.99],["2008",4000],["2009",5087.42],["2010",6584.68],["2011",4000],["2012",4000],["2013",4000],["2014",29458.22],["2015",4068.58],["2016",4000.01],["2017",4000.12],["2018",4000],["2019",4003.91],["2020",8956.47],["2021",4000],["2022",4000],["2023",4000],["2024",4000],["2025",4264.9],["2026",4222.05],["2027",4039.94],["2028",4019.64],["2029",4000],["2030",4000.34],["2031",4279.83],["2032",4000],["2033",4006.69],["2034",4000],["2035",4000],["2036",4000],["2037",4000],["2038",4000],["2039",4000],["2040",4000],["2041",4000],["2042",4000],["2043",4627.18],["2044",4000],["2045",4000],["2046",4000],["2047",4000.11],["2048",4000],["2049",4000.04],["2050",4000.19]]},{"key":"City32","values":[["1990",6428.59],["1991",7079.34],["1992",4014.61],["1993",4000.77],["1994",4005.34],["1995",4182.21],["1996",4034.73],["1997",5891.87],["1998",4735.89],["1999",4039.58],["2000",4000],["2001",5030.29],["2002",4000.03],["2003",4000.43],["2004",4321.92],["2005",12575.87],["2006",4000],["2007",4027.99],["2008",4000],["2009",5087.42],["2010",6584.68],["2011",4000],["2012",4000],["2013",4000],["2014",29458.22],["2015",4068.58],["2016",4000.01],["2017",4000.12],["2018",4000],["2019",4003.91],["2020",8956.47],["2021",4000],["2022",4000],["2023",4000],["2024",4000],["2025",4264.9],["2026",4222.05],["2027",4039.94],["2028",4019.64],["2029",4000],["2030",4000.34],["2031",4279.83],["2032",4000],["2033",4006.69],["2034",4000],["2035",4000],["2036",4000],["2037",4000],["2038",4000],["2039",4000],["2040",4000],["2041",4000],["2042",4000],["2043",4627.18],["2044",4000],["2045",4000],["2046",4000],["2047",4000.11],["2048",4000],["2049",4000.04],["2050",4000.19]]}]
```

Code:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.cumulativeLineChart()
                      .x(function(d) { return d[0] })
                      .y(function(d) { return d[1] }) //adjusting, 100% is 1.00, not 100 as it is in the data
                      .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
                      .useInteractiveGuideline(false); 
        //chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.0d'));
        d3.select('#chart2 svg')
            .datum(chartdata)
            .call(chart);
        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
return chart;
    });
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: the y scale is percent in cumulativeLineChart and you passing values as high as this 7079.34 thats teh reason why its drawing the scale wrong...looking at your values you should be using simple line chart

Comment: Thanks Cyril **Issue Resolved**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a line chart not a cumulative chart.

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
              .x(function(d) { return d[0] })
              .y(function(d) { console.log(d);return d[1] }) 
              .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
              .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
              ;
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/jx6qmnxL/1/)

Hope this helps!